# Etiquette on removing wrong answer after a downvote

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-answers, etiquette, self-delete

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I remove a wrong answer (Peer Pressure)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22630/should-i-remove-a-wrong-answer-peer-pressure)
>   [When or should you delete your incorrect answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/when-or-should-you-delete-your-incorrect-answer)

What's the etiquette on removing your wrong answer after a downvote? Say, for example, I answered a question, and then realized it was out of context or wrong.

Scenario 1: Nobody has downvoted or responded to it. I'll go in and remove it - which seems to be fine; I'm correcting myself and keeping the site clean.

Scenario 2: I didn't realize my answer was wrong/out of context until someone downvoted it or put in a comment to point it out (and, of course, I realize my mistake). Is it okay if I remove my answer now (to keep the site clean and to correct myself)? Or is it not okay, as it might seem I'm covering up my bad deeds?

p.s., This is different from [Proper way to correct a mistaken answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38469/proper-way-to-correct-a-mistaken-answer), as I would be removing it and probably not providing another answer as I might not have a correct answer.

p.p.s., The Peer Pressure badge to me seems like a 'negative badge'. Like an 'always just in time' badge that might actually mean you are a Late Comer. Should I look forward to getting the Peer Pressure badge?

Comment: @Martin - probably, but there OP is removing it because s/he does not want to confront the user. Here - I know I'm wrong, but don't have the correct answer. I'll confront and fight if I think I'm right :)

Comment: @Arjan - You are right. I probably missed it in my search. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You might be right about the question a linked, but the one linked by Arjan looks like the correct duplicate.

Comment: It's a duplicate indeed @Arjan, though the concerning point is slightly different: this *should be* about etiquette, the other is about content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. The only scenario it could be slightly bad is if you're actually engaging a discussion in comments.

Just keep in mind downvotes work differently in meta and main sites. On meta they traditionally mean "disagree", while on main they actually mean "bad".

And, like everyone else said, **maybe** you should wait until it reaches -3 to get the [peer pressure badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/36/peer-pressure)! Answering your edit, *almost* all badges are meant to be a good thing. They exist to give an incentive for good behavior, just like in scouts badges. But some people will always see some badges as they wish.

Comment: +1 - thanks for pointing out the difference in downvote, I didn't realized it.

Comment: @Yetano One thing the answers have all not mentioned yet, but remember - deleted posts do not contribute reputation change, but this only applies after a reputation recalculation. We still keep track of the fact you got downvoted (which only comes into play if you have a significant history of poor posting), but this is a way you can regain the reputation from that downvote, basically noting that you've "atoned" for your mistake.

Comment: @Grace - yes I realize that. I would not delete to regain but to clear the space when I clearly know my answer is wrong. Thanks for pointing though.

Comment: Great point @Grace.

Comment: @Yetano I'd call that motive for deletion all the more reason you deserve to have the reputation back. ♪

Comment: Not all badges are to incentivize good behavior. "Disciplined" certainly isn't. And "Tumbleweed" is mostly a consolation prize.

Comment: @Cawas You are right, may be I was looking at the badge with some prejudice :)

Comment: @Gabe true. fixed. ;)   @Yetano attention to what Gabe said! :P

Comment: @Gabe, @Cawas - Not sure if I agree. If I answered a question incorrectly (missing a subtle point) and 3 or more people also missed it and up voted it, still I go back in and remove my answer on realizing the missed point - I'm definitely 'disciplined' and in a positive way and demonstrating good behavior. May be expected behavior was to edit the answer and explain why it was wrong and point to the subtle point originally missed.

Comment: @Gabe "Disciplined" may be very disciplined if, for example, your answer was actually outdated or otherwise misleading, and that you thus delete it to better highlight the more correct data of other answers. It may also be done in the case where two or more users post the exact same answer at the same time - one deleting their answer to allow the other one to keep their reputation while not keeping what is basically a redundancy of information. That it comes with a price of losing the reputation from upvotes, that is what makes it an action of discipline.

Comment: @Yetano I meant he was right that "*not all badges are to incentivize good behavior*" mostly because of Tumbleweed. I never gave any thought on the other one. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can remove it. There is even a badge for removing bad answers: Peer pressure.

Comment: +1 just because you've answered 1 second before Brandon! :P

Answer (score 6):

It's fine to remove bad answers. There is even the Peer Pressure badge for removing an answer that has a score of -3 or lower.